# How to run RStudio Server with SELinux enabled?

Tags: r, selinux, rstudio-server

RStudio Server is failing to log in user when SELinux is enforcing. There is a long list of SELinux errors, starting with:

> AVC avc: denied { setpgid } for pid=32444 comm="rserver"
>   scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0
>   tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tclass=process permissive=0

RStudio Server runs fine when SELinux is in permissive mode, albeit with a lot of alerts:

[image]

RStudio maintainers don't consider this a bug and closed the [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4937). Meanwhile, given how niche RStudio Server is, it might be a while before Fedora implements SELinux policy for it, though they have not rejected the [request](https://github.com/fedora-selinux/selinux-policy-contrib/issues/116).

Is anyone running RStudio Server successfully with SELinux enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo chcon -R -t bin_t /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/
```

This gives the binaries the right context, since they are for some reason in a directory for libraries.

However, this solution lets RStudio Server run unconstrained since no targeted policy exists for it yet.

Comment: I got the same problem and this worked. I had to `sudo rstudio-server restart` to get RStudio Server to load in server after this.